# XAML style BasedOn TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock which has `Style={TemplateBinding ParentDependencyProperty}`

I need to place some DataTriggers on just this TextBlock, but not on the style as a whole.

I need something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Style BasedOn="StyleInParentDependencyProperty">
        <Style.Triggers>
            ...
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And I can't figure out how, as no bindings are allowed in the BasedOn property of Styles. I am pretty new to WPF, and seemingly stuck here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Default">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32pt" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#777777" />
</Style>
```

And define this style just on your `TextBlock` that need some `DataTriggers`

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}" TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockWithTriggers">
   <Style.Triggers> .... </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And on your `TextBlock` just define

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockWithTriggers}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Thanks. There's no way to get the exact style from the TemplateBinding and mark it as a StaticResource and use that in BasedOn?